# How to avoid loading half rendered pages in asp.net application?

Tags: asp.net

For our Asp.Net web forms application when we enter something like random text after.aspx(Home.aspx/sfsfds) , it is showing page like half rendered page(which is not having styles but page controls are loaded). This issue we are considering as vulnerability to our application. How to fix this?

Comment: No one can help you fix a bug in your application when you don't specify *any* information, not even whether it's WebForms or MVC. It's obvious though that what you call "partial pages" are full pages that simply don't have all the stuff you though they would.

Comment: It's web forms application, when we enter something after .aspx extension of the page in the browser(http://localhost/Home.aspx/dsfadfda), it is loading the Home.aspx page without loading styles.

Comment: In MVC there are partial views, not partial pages. In Web Forms there is partial rendering,  master pages. Again, no partial pages. And the comment still doesn't make sense - in fact it's the opposite of the original question. Either you are loading a page named `sfsfds` which you didn't want, or your Home page has a bug that causes it to crash when it sees that `sfsfds`

Comment: And why are you considering it as vulnerability to begin with? This is not exposing any information user wouldn't see from the page itself.

Comment: i think your style file does not load because addresses are relative. check your style file loading status with your browser developer tools

Comment: Just go to this link http://webproject.scottgu.com/CSharp/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.aspx and after that go to this link http://webproject.scottgu.com/CSharp/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.aspx/sdfsdfsdffs. You will see the difference. Some security tools showing this as vulnerability. I also do not know that tool name as it is came from client side third party testing team.

Comment: I do not know what to call that half rendered pages, so refereed them as partial loaded pages in the question.

Comment: @Damirchi has the correct answer.

Comment: It looks more like a WebServer issue (IIS?) to me, since it is allowing an intermediate path element to be dynamically processed without redirecting to the actual path.